# Java testing verifying constructor

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am trying to figure out a way to verify a class constructor in the following way (keep in mind this is a theoretical example)

```
public MyClass extends ItemContainer {

   public MyClass(RoundItem a, SquareItem b) {
      addItem(a);
      addItem(b); 
   }
}
```

I would like to verify that the constructor called addItem once with any(RoundItem.class) and once with any(SquareItem.class). I can't seem to find a good way to verify a constructor in such a way with PowerMock or Mockito. Any ideas?

Comment: Why is it not sufficient to verify that exactly one round item and one square item were added?

Comment: That would be sufficient. But lets say for this exercise that MyClass is readonly.  There is no way to 'getItems()' or a similar type access pattern after the item is constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a mocking framework in order to test this. You can make [Test Spy](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Spy.html) object.

for example :

```
@Test
public void testMyClassConstruction() throws Exception {
  MyClass myClass = new MyClass() {
    public int size() {
      return items.size();
    }
  }

  assertEquals(2, myClass.size());
}
```

Comment: This omits the need to assert their order of insertion as well as type.

Comment: @Matt You can do whatever you want in the Test Spy object, it dose not has to be like this. For example, let spy return the items for you, then you can assert the order and type.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should beware from putting any logic into your constructor. (in order not to test them. Items `a` and `b` may be placed into the container by the client code (and you can actually use mocking frameworks to test it, but there are easier ways to do it).

Consider checking out [Misko Hevery's](http://misko.hevery.com/) set of lectures on testing to get sufficient background to get unit testing right.

Answer (score 0):

Mockite is purely used for Mocking purposes, if you would like to test other things I would suggest you take a look at JUnit. It's one of the best testing frameworks for Java.
Otherwise you can always just System.out.print in your constructor to find out how many times it's called.

Comment: A system.out would not be a very good test. Such testing can not be automated and ensure quality in product the development lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Verifications() {
           {        
            addItem(a); times=1;
            addItem(b); times=1;
            }
        };
```

This way you can test whether the methods where called.In this you can mock objects "a" & "b"

Or you could use "withInsatceLike"

Ex:

```
 addItem(withInsatceLike(a));
```

Hope this helps